# SSH login to a Digitalocean Droplet is not responding

Tags: python-3.x, digital-ocean

I am trying to use `ssh` to login to my Digitalocean droplet, but the following command is not asking (accepting) [E.N.: unclear which one the OP means] the password and does not respond.

```
ssh name@ip_address
```

Comment: make sure you added your ssh key to server authorized keys file.

Comment: can you clarify if the ssh command does not ask for your password OR does not accept your password?

Answer (score 2):

It's probable that the username for the host is `root`.

If you request a password to be mailed to you, you'll get the username (probably `root`), password and IP address (`${ADDR}`) in the mail and can:

```
ssh root@${ADDR}
```

and provide the password when prompted. If you created the droplet and referenced an existing ssh-key, then you won't be emailed a password. You can use the same command but you won't be prompted for a password.

I have multiple ssh key(pairs) and I generally, provide the specific key (in my case `id_digitalocean`) to the command too:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_digitalocean root@${ADDR}
```